# Apart from Veer Savarkar and S.A. Dange, were there any Indian revolutionaries who filed mercy petitions to the British?

Tags: india, independence

In today's Indian politics, it is often pointed out by anti-Hindutva political parties that Veer Savarkar, an Indian freedom fighter and founder of the Hindutva philosophy, wrote mercy petitions to the British during his imprisonment. This political tactic is used in order to portray Savarkar as an Indian revolutionary who turned British stooge in later years.

Conveniently, it is often forgotten that S.A. Dange, a founding member of the Communist Party of India and also an Indian freedom fighter, during his imprisonment, wrote similar mercy petitions to the British.

My question is, are there any other revolutionaries apart from Veer Savarkar and S.A. Dange during the Indian freedom struggle, who in imprisonment, wrote similar mercy petitions to the British?

P.S. It would be appreciated if anyone could provide excerpts of such mercy petitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is one by one of the co founders of HSRA [Shri Sachchindranath Sanyal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachindra_Nath_Sanyal) who in his autobiography *Bandi Jeevan* mentions that he wrote a similar clemency petition as that of Savarkar when they both were in Andaman in 1917-18... he was released but Savarkar wasn't...